# Show that $F$ is an holomorphic function function on $\Omega\smallsetminus\mathbb{R}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let be $\Omega = \{z \in \mathbb{C} , z \neq 0, z \neq 1 \}$ 
For $z \in \Omega\smallsetminus\mathbb{R^-}$ we define:

$$F(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{(\log(z) + 2in\pi)^2}$$

where log is the principal determination of logarithme.

I want to Show that $F$ is an holomorphic function function on $\Omega \smallsetminus \mathbb{R^-}$

Comment: You shouldn't alternate in and out of MathJax in the course of writing something like $$ \Omega = \{ z\in\mathbb C, z\ne0 \}. $$ It should all be between a pair of dollar signs or double dollar signs. Likewise $z\in\Omega\smallsetminus\mathbb R,$ etc. $\qquad$

Comment: ok thank you for edit. i m a beginner in latex that's why i can't know all symbols yet

Comment: If you allow $n=0$ then you have a pole at $z=1$

Comment: Note you can say more : $f(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(z+2i \pi n)^2}$ is $2i\pi $ periodic and meromorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ with poles at $2i \pi n$, ie. $f(z)$ is meromorphic on $\mathbb{C} / 2i\pi \mathbb{Z}$ with a pole at $z=0$,

and $\log(z)$ is holomorphic $\mathbb{C}^* \to \mathbb{C} / 2i\pi \mathbb{Z}$


thus $F(z ) = f(\log(z))$ is meromorphic on $\mathbb{C}^*$ with a pole at $\log(z) = 0 \implies z=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $U = \mathbb C \setminus (-\infty,0].$ For $n=1,2, \dots $ and $z\in U,$

$$|\log z + i2n\pi|^2 = |\ln |z| + i(\text { arg }(z) +2n\pi)|^2 = \ln^2 |z| + (\text { arg }(z) +2n\pi)^2.$$

Since $\text { arg }(z) > -\pi,$ the last term is at least $(2n-1)^2\pi^2.$ Therefore

$$\left | \frac{1}{(\log z + i2n\pi)^2}\right | \le \frac{1}{(2n-1)^2\pi^2}.$$

Thus $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{(\log z + i2n\pi)^2}$ converges uniformly on $U$ by the Weierstrass M-test. Since a uniformly convergent series of holomorphic functions is holomorphic, we see this series defines a holomorphic function on $U.$ Same for $\sum_{n<0} \dfrac{1}{(\log z + i2n\pi)^2}.$ Thus

$$\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z,n\ne 0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(\log z + i2n\pi)^2}$$

is holomorphic on $U.$ (If you allow $n=0$ then $F$ has a pole of order $2$ at $1\in U.$)

Answer (score 1):

For $n \in \mathbb N$ and $z \in D$ (where $D=\Omega\setminus \mathbb R_-$), let $$f_n(z)=\frac{1}{(\log(z) + 2in\pi)^2}.$$

$f_n$ is holoporphic and
$$f_n^\prime(z)=-\frac{2}{z(\log z+2in\pi)^3}.$$

For $z_0 \in D$ and using the properties of the complex logarithm, try to define a compact set $K$ such that $z_0$ belongs to the interior of $K$ and such that there exists $A,B > 0$ with $\vert z \vert > A$ and $\vert \log z \vert  >B$ for $z \in K$.

You then have $$\vert f_n^\prime(z) \vert < \left\vert \frac{2}{A(2n\pi-B)^3} \right\vert$$ for $z \in K$. As the sum on $n \in \mathbb N$ of the RHS of above inequality converges, $\sum f_n^\prime(z)$ converges normally on the interior of $K$. This proves that $F$ is holomorphic on a neighborhood of $z_0$. As this this is true for any $z_0 \in D$, we get the desired conclusion.